# How to execute multiple functions in parallel in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to execute multiple functions in parallel in spark batch using scala?

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 def func1() {
 // dataframe 1 write to oracle database table 1
 }
 def func2() {
 // dataframe 2 write to oracle database table 2
 }
 def func3() { 
 // dataframe 3 write to oracle database table 3
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, but simply using multi-threading should do the trick

Comment: Probably you only need to use **Future**.

Comment: Using spark scala i am writing 3 different transformed dataframes to different tables in rdbms using, which should be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In general concurrency can be achieved using Futures... following the example below you can try on your own...

see [Concurrency in Spark](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/)

```
/** A singleton object that controls the parallelism on a Single Executor JVM, Using the GlobalContext **/
object ConcurrentContext {
  import scala.util._
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  /** Wraps a code block in a Future and returns the future */
  def executeAsync[T](f: => T): Future[T] = {
    Future(f)
  }
}
```

and then

```
scala> sc.parallelize( 1 to 10).map(fastFoo).map(x => ConcurrentContext.executeAsync(slowFoo(x))).collect
fastFoo(1)
fastFoo(2)
fastFoo(3)
fastFoo(4)
slowFoo start (2)
slowFoo start (1)
fastFoo(5)
slowFoo start (3)
  ...
res6: Array[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]] = Array(List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List())

scala>  // Our request returns
//Then 5 seconds later
slowFoo end(1)
slowFoo end(7)
slowFoo end(8)
slowFoo end(4)
slowFoo start (10)
slowFoo end(5)
```